# drawerLayout overlapping fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have been at this problem for a while

I believe its because something is not correct with the drawerLayout implementation, even tho I followed the developer site to implement it.

I have an activity, that for now has 3 frames, mangaSearch(mS)(recyclerView), profile, settings
mS is the start fragment, when i go to the drawer menu and select profile or settings, the fragments are drawn above the mS fragment.   when i hit back the mS fragment is shown normal again, as intended.

I have looked around on google/stack but have not found a solution for this problem, hence I am asking here for help.

**Update**
I had the wrong id's in drawer, i had to change them in to the ones from the navigation nav_graph layout.

mainActivity

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import Classes.LoggedInUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfig;

    public static LoggedInUser loggedInUser;
    FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loggedInUser = LoggedInUser.getInstance();
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        appBarConfig = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_graph_manga_book_details,
                R.id.nav_graph_mangas_search_souce, R.id.nav_graph_profile,
                R.id.nav_graph_settings).setDrawerLayout(drawer).build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_content);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfig);
        //NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


        DrawerLayout drawerL = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerL);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {


                                                             @Override
                                                             public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                                                                 int id = item.getItemId();
                                                                 switch (id) {
                                                                     case R.id.nav_manga_books_source:
                                                                         fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, new MangasSearchFragment(), "mangaBookSource").commit();
                                                                         break;
                                                                     case R.id.nav_user_profile:
                                                                         //check if person is logged in?
                                                                         fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, new ProfileFragment(), "profile").commit();
                                                                         break;

                                                                     case R.id.nav_settings:
                                                                         fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, new SettingsFragment(), "settings").commit();
                                                                         break;
                                                                     case R.id.nav_settings_temp:
                                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings Temp works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                         break;

                                                                 }
                                                                 drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                                                 return true;

                                                             }
                                                         });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_content);
            return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfig) || super.onSupportNavigateUp();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
       else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

The layout file

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />




</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

layout drawer_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_user_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_user_profile"
            android:title="Profile" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manga_books_source"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_manga_books_of_source"
            android:title="Manga's"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="Settings"/>
    </group>
    <item android:title="new group">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings_temp"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                android:title="Settings temp" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

the later added navigation component recommended by someone. The problem was there already and this did not fix it, as it was not intended as a fix, but it might be relevant to the mainActivity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_graph_mangas_search_souce">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_mangas_search_souce"
        android:name="com.example.what2watchmangareader.MangasSearchFragment"
        android:label="start fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mangas_to_search" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_profile"
        android:name="com.example.what2watchmangareader.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="profile page"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_settings"
        android:name="com.example.what2watchmangareader.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="Settings Page"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_manga_book_details"
        android:name="com.example.what2watchmangareader.MangaBookFragment"
        android:label="Manga detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_manga_book_info" />

    //Add your other fragments here.
</navigation>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any FragmentTransactions (nor do you really need the `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` call at all) when you're using NavHostFragment. What happens when you remove that code entirely?

Comment: This will stop me from getting to the fragments choosen in the drawer menu, so the drawer menu stays open and nothing happends clicking on a menu(settings/mS/profile)

Comment: Do your `android:id` of your menu items match those in your navigation graph as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)? It doesn't look like they match.

Comment: i changed the ones in drawer_menu to the ones from nav_grap  in navigation, and now i do not need the setOnClickListener, thank you for the direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), you don't need to run any FragmentTransactions nor do you need to manually implement a `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` when using `setupWithNavController()`. Instead, you only need to match the `android:id` between your navigation graph and menu items.